# Constructions of complex surfaces covered by the ball of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, lattices, algebraic-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Let $S$ be a compact complex surface. It is well-known that the following two facts are equivalent

1. $c_1^2(S) = 3 c_2(S)$ and $S \neq \mathbb{CP}^2$
2. The universal cover of $S$ is biholomorphic to the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

The unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is biholomorphic the complex hyperbolic plane $\mathbf{H}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ and its group of biholomorphisms is $\mathrm{PU}(1,2)$. Consequently, a compact complex surface is the same thing as the datum of a torsion-free, co-compact lattice in $\mathrm{PU}(1,2)$.

My question is : are there constructions of such surfaces that do not transit through lattices in $\mathrm{PU}(1,2)$? For instance, are there constructions of surfaces satisfying $c_1^2(S) = 3 c_2(S)$ coming from algebraic geometry, or from ramified covering-type of construction?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. There is even a book by Hirzebruch and his students on this.

Comment: Nice one, what's the name of the book?

Comment: Lev Borisov and collaborators have a series of papers on equations of fake projective planes arXiv:1710.04501, arXiv:1802.06333, arXiv:1804.00737, arXiv:2004.02637,  arXiv:2008.09731, arXiv:2109.02070.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are two book references, both originating in the 1983 paper by Hirzebruch:

*Hirzebruch, Friedrich*, Arrangements of lines and algebraic surfaces, Arithmetic and geometry, Pap. dedic. I. R. Shafarevich, Vol. II: Geometry, Prog. Math. 36, 113-140 (1983). [ZBL0527.14033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0527.14033).

*Barthel, Gottfried; Hirzebruch, Friedrich; Höfer, Thomas*, Geradenkonfigurationen und algebraische Flächen. (Configurations of lines and algebraic surfaces). Eine Veröffentlichung des Max-Planck-Instituts für Mathematik, Bonn, Aspects of Mathematics, D4. Braunschweig/Wiesbaden: Friedr. Vieweg & Sohn. XII, 308 S.; (1987). [ZBL0645.14016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0645.14016).

*Tretkoff, Paula*, [**Complex ball quotients and line arrangements in the projective plane. With an appendix by Hans-Christoph Im Hof**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9781400881253), Mathematical Notes (Princeton) 51. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press (ISBN 978-0-691-14477-1/pbk; 978-1-400-88125-3/ebook). ix, 215 p. (2016). [ZBL1342.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1342.14001).

In this approach, ball quotients are constructed via a combination of blow-ups and (finite) ramified coverings of $P^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Tretkoff's book is not open access, so I couldn't get much from these references unfortunately. It seems Hirzebruch in his original article builds only three such surfaces, do these methods yield more than that? Hopefully an infinity?

Comment: @SelimG: From what I know, there are only finitely many **explicitly known** commensurabilify classes. If you find one example, you get infinitely many by taking unramified finite coverings.

Answer (score 1):

Another relevant reference is:

Hirzebruch, F.(D-MPI)
Chern numbers of algebraic surfaces: an example.
Math. Ann.266(1984), no.3, 351–356.

The surface called W_3 there is an example.

For open surfaces (<=> nonuniform lattices) there are more examples, discussed in this paper of Hirzebruch and in the work of Holzapfel.